# How to construct a bivariate distribution from marginal distributions with a predefined correlation

Tags: distributions, correlation, simulation, copula, bivariate

I would like to generate zipf and lognormal random variables with a particular correlation. Then, I would like to find their bivariate distribution. What approach should I follow?.

Comment: Can you give a little more details, what do you want to achieve? Do you have data from which to estimate the correlation, or the complete bivariate distribution?

Comment: What I want to achieve is this, On the internet, file popularity is modelled as zipf distribution and file size is modelled as a lognormal distribution. In literature, there is no available bivariate distribution for the two distributions that describe the joint distribution of file popularity and file size. What I want to do is generate zipf and lognormal distributions with some correlation , say, 0.5. Then, I want to find the bivariate distribution (possibly using copula). Is my approach correct?.

Comment: You can simulate $(U_1, U_2)$ from some bivarite copula with correlation $\rho=0.5$.  That random pair will have (by definition of copula) uniform marginals.  Then you use those two correlated uniforms to generate the lognormal and zipf variaates, through the usual inversion procedure.  Usually, one uses rank correlation, so that the meaning of the correlation is preserved.

Comment: Do I have to use copula to generate $U_{1},U_{2}$. Can I generate two correlated $(U_{1},U_{2})$as following $U_{1}=X_{1}$ and $U_{2}=\rho X_{1}+\sqrt(1-\rho^2) X_{2}$ where $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are independent uniform random variables. Then, I use $(U_{1},U_{2})$ to generate dependent zipf and lognormal distributions using inverse technique.

Comment: Your $U_2$ above would not be uniform on $(0,1)$, so no ...

Comment: Thanks. You are right, $U_{2}$ is not uniform. I followed your approach using Gaussian copula. After generating $(U_{1},U_{2})$ using Gaussian copula with $\rho = 0.5$ for example, I calculated the correlation between $U_{1}$ and $(U_{2})$. The result is $\rho =0.408$, not $\rho=0.5$.

Comment: You probably used the linear correlation. That will be changed by the nonlinear transformation! To avoid that, us rank correlation.

Answer (score 1):

First simulate $(U_1, U_2)$ from a bivariate copula you must choose. 
Then  $U_1$ will be uniform on $(0,1)$ as will $U_2$, by the definition of a copula. You choose the copula by having the right rank correlation coefficient, for example Kendall's $\tau$.  You must use rank correlation because then the nonlinear (but monotone) transformation we are going to use, will preserve the correlation. That will not happen if you use the linear Pearson correlation, thats why that is not so well suited to use with copulas.

Now let $F_1$ be your Zipf cumulative distribution function(cdf) and $F_2$ the lognormal one.  Now you use the probability integral transformation and define
$$
  X_1 =F_1^{-1}(U_1), \\
   X_2 = F_2^{-1}(U_2)
$$
Then we are done.

Comment: Thanks you kjetil b halvorsen. Actually what I want to generate is a set of files, say $N_{f}=100$.. Let X be the popularity of files described by a zipf distribution described by $X=1,2,...N_{f}$. The file size distribution is assumed to be lognormal distribution. This means for a particular file, for example the most popular file $(X=1)$, the file has a particular size drawn from a lognormal distribution. If I follow your suggestion, then the most popular file  $X=1$ will be associated with more than one file size.